# how to iterate dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

I am trying to read all the elements in a dictionary one by one. my dictionary is as given below "test".

```
test ={'line4': (4, 2), 'line3': (3, 2), 'line2': (2, 2), 'line1': (1, 2), 'line10': (10, 2)}
```

i want to do as given in below sample code.

```
for i in range(1,len(test)+1):
    print test(1) # should print all the values one by one
```

thank you

Comment: To be clear: You have a dict of tuples. `{'line4': (4, 2)}` is one element. `(4,2)` is the tuple value that is mapped to `line4`. A Python dict is not sorted.

Comment: _Sample output_ would enhance this question and maybe even make it useful for this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few possibilities. Your question is quite vague and your code isn't even close to working, so it's difficult to understand the question

```
>>> test ={'line4': (4, 2), 'line3': (3, 2), 'line2': (2, 2), 'line1': (1, 2), 'line10': (10, 2)}
>>> for i in test.items():
...     print i
... 
('line4', (4, 2))
('line3', (3, 2))
('line2', (2, 2))
('line1', (1, 2))
('line10', (10, 2))
>>> for i in test:
...     print i
... 
line4
line3
line2
line1
line10
>>> for i in test.values():
...     print i
... 
(4, 2)
(3, 2)
(2, 2)
(1, 2)
(10, 2)
>>> for i in test.values():
...     for j in i:
...         print j
... 
4
2
3
2
2
2
1
2
10
2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#Given a dictionary
>>> test ={'line4': (4, 2), 'line3': (3, 2), 'line2': (2, 2), 'line1': (1, 2), 'line10': (10, 2)}

#And if you want a list of tuples, what you need actually is the values of the dictionary
>>> test.values()
[(4, 2), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (10, 2)]

#Instead if you want a flat list of values, you can flatten using chain/chain.from_iterable
>>> list(chain(*test.values()))
[4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 10, 2]
#And to print the list 
>>> for v in chain.from_iterable(test.values()):
    print v


4
2
3
2
2
2
1
2
10
2
```

Analyzing your code

```
for i in range(1,len(test)+1):
    print test(1) # should print all the values one by one
```

1. You can't index a dictionary. A dictionary is not a sequence like a list
2. You don;t use parenthesis to index. It turns to be a function call
3. To iterate a dictionary, you can either iterate the keys or the values.

   1. `for key in test` to iterate a dictionary by keys
   2. `for key in test.values()` to iterate a dictionary by values

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for v in test.values():
    for val in v:
        print val
```

if you need a list:

```
print [val for v in test.values() for val in v ]
```

If you want to print each record from dict than:

```
for k, v in test.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested comprehension:

```
>>> test ={'line4': (4, 2), 'line3': (3, 2), 'line2': (2, 2), 'line1': (1, 2), 'line10': (10, 2)}
>>> print '\n'.join(str(e) for t in test.values() for e in t)
4
2
3
2
2
2
1
2
10
2
```

Since dictionaries are unsorted in Python, your tuples will be unsorted as well.